# .Net Maui Launcher URL for App Store/Google Play

Tags: google-play, app-store, maui, launcher

Reading about the launcher it gives the example of starting the Lyft app by doing something like:

```
await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("lyft://ridetype?id=lyft_line");
```

I can't find examples for doing something with the app store or google play store like:

```
await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync("appStore://app?id=1234567");
```

Is this even a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can try to use [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios#open-another-app) to open another app and determine if the app can be opened by [CanOpenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.applicationmodel.ilauncher.canopenasync?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-applicationmodel-ilauncher-canopenasync(system-uri)) method (If not, open `Playstore` or `AppStore`, you should know the redirection link to Google Play store or Apple AppStore.)

For example, you want to launch Microsoft Word with `AppStore`.

1.Get the deep link for the Microsoft Word https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-word/id586447913 via [app-store](https://www.apple.com/app-store/)

2.And then you can launch it via below code:

```
bool launcherOpened = await Launcher.Default.TryOpenAsync("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-word/id586447913");

if (launcherOpened)
{
    // Do something fun
}
```

Comment: Nice. I assumed that the link would be different format than https:// because of the example but i used my same app link and it goes direct to the app store instead of Chrome then the App Store. Thanks